# I have different last names on passport and local official identity, which one should I use for publication?

Tags: publications, authorship, personal-name

I'll soon publish my first scientific journal but I encountered a problem.

I have two different last names in which both are official. For example: in my national identity card (as well as my birth certificate, school certificate up to university) my name is John Adam. However in my passport, I put an additional word so my name became John Adam Levine. I took a double degree program and when I'm abroad doing research this is the name I used (also for school certificate) and the research is about to be published.

Which name should I use for publication? I heard that it's okay as long as it is consistent, but I wonder if I will get into trouble for it someday. Preferably I'd like to use the first one because the only reason I put the third word is because I need it to go to a certain country, however I'm concerned because this is the name I used for my abroad school certificate.

I'm now really desperate because I have to decide soon. Any advise or similar experience will be helpful

Thank You!

Comment: Why was this downvoted?

Comment: It doesn't matter much which one you choose to use, but you'll want to pick one and stick with it, so that people searching for your publications later on can identify you.

Answer (score 5):

From a practical perspective: you might also want to consider to check a major publication database of your field and see, if one of the two possibilities / names has not been used by another researcher. This might become useful once people look for your publications.